# matching 8 or 9 digits using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have what I think is a simple regex question - i'm fairly new to regex, so, i have it down about 90% (i think!) on this issue.

I need to match one of two strings (all digits) inside a text box.

```
 1. ####-####
 2. ########
```

so, first string is 9 characters, with the '-' in the middle. second string is 8 digits with no '-' in there.

what i got is:

```
/[\d]{4}-??[\d]{4}/
```

which works pretty well, BUT, since i have to allow for 9 characters because of the first option, this also validates ######### (9 digits), since the first 8 match the expression.

so, how do i do this?

I thought perhaps including [^\d]? at the end would do it (optional, non digit, which would makes the 9th digits break the match), but, that didn't do...

Thanks for reading!

Comment: first string is 8 digits with `-`

Comment: yes, it is. what's your point?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Which is 9 *characters*

Comment: I don't really understand what your question is. Can you include some examples that are valid or invalid?

Comment: Juhana has the answer I think. It's not a problem about number of characters, but an anchors problem.

Comment: Is the sequence with a hyphen so fundamentally different than a sequence without one, that you don't just strip the hyphen and/or deny entries that are not an integer? Juhana's answer is what you are looking for, but consider if regex is even necessary for your use case.

Comment: @tremor, I can do that, OR, I can use Juhana's answer, which is more elegant ;)

Comment: @raingod: if (str.length > 8 || isNan(str))  - elegance is in the eye of the beholder. Don't be afraid to put some responsibility on your end user to type things in properly.

Comment: "Don't be afraid to put some responsibility on your end user to type things in properly." famous last words. i think you can assume that if a user CAN do it wrong, at one point or another, one of them will :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the start-of-line and end-of-line markers to make sure only this pattern matches.

```
/^[\d]{4}-?[\d]{4}$/
```

Comment: You can remove square brackets.

Answer (score 6):

Use `^` and `$`:

```
'00000000'.match(/^\d{4}-?\d{4}$/) // true
'0000-0000'.match(/^\d{4}-?\d{4}$/) // true
'000000000'.match(/^\d{4}-?\d{4}$/) // nil
```

`^` matches the beginning of the string; `$` matches the end. Without them, you're matching any substring. So your original regex would match a 20-digit string, for example.